# why I can't ssh into the instance with hostname in GCP?

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, instance

I have an instance in the name of `welynxcore`, I have no problem SSH into it via Console.

[image]

I opened Cloud Shell commandline, and see if I can ssh from there:

[image]

So it doesn't allow me to do so with the error:

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname welynxcore: Name or service not known

What am I missing here? Is it allowed to ssh in Cloud Shell? Below is the list of instances:

[image]

which instance am I on when I open Cloud Shell?

```
xenonxie@cloudshell:~ (rock-perception-263016)$ hostname
cs-6000-devshell-vm-8e59d29e-e820-4b08-aea1-b04d4a597711
```

Which instance `cs-6000-devshell-vm-8e59d29e-e820-4b08-aea1-b04d4a597711` refers to?

Thank you for your enlightening in advance.

**[UPDATE]**

From VM instances, I see the instance was granted a public ip address: `34.67.190.134`, without making any change to the default security settings, I attempted to SSH into it withing Cloud Shell and received the following message:

```
xenonxie@cloudshell:~ (rock-perception-263016)$ ssh 34.67.190.134
```

> The authenticity of host '34.67.190.134 (34.67.190.134)' can't be
>   established. ECDSA key fingerprint is
>   SHA256:mVzPEGPrWIuEXcojJTgwpinWO4eB2RwupWVA/Ix7Ko4. Are you sure you
>   want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes Warning: Permanently added
>   '34.67.190.134' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts. Permission denied
>   (publickey).

Seems I need to store the instance's public key on the "free" default vm instance assigned to my GCP account? am I right? Where is the public key file and is there an easy way to transfer/import that key?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5):

When you create a Cloud Shell command line, a VM is created that is an instance of a `g1-small`  (see [How Cloud Shell works](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/how-cloud-shell-works)).  This is a free instance.  It is **not** a Compute Engine VM instance that shows up under your instances under a project.  In fact, your Cloud Shell instance is associated with your GCP login identity and *not* associated with any single project.  Thus any persistent data you have is present when you open up the Cloud Shell on any currently selected project.   This should answer your first question ... the Cloud Shell is *none* of the instances listed under your project's VM instances.

Now we get to talk about networking.  If you login to Cloud Shell and run `ip addr` you will see the instance's IP addresses.  What you will find is that they don't correspond to *any* of your VPC Network's known entries.  Putting it another way, there is no network path from your Cloud Shell to your VM instances over your VPC network.  Your Cloud Shell instance *does* have Internet connectivity.  What this means is that you can reach your VM instances from Cloud Shell as long as you reach them through the VM instances public IP address (assuming they have one).

**Update for the Update**:
Once you have exposed your VM with a public IP, you can use SSH to login.  However, SSH requires that you have a private key (local to where you are running ssh) and also that the target (VM) have authorized the corresponding public key as allowed to login.

There are a few stories at play here.  The first is that you can create a public/private key pair and add your public key to the SSH keys through the GCP console or corresponding gcloud command.  See:

[Connecting to instances using advanced methods](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced)

However, an easier way is to login (through SSH) using generated key pairs (this is easier).  You can use the `gcloud compute ssh` command for this.  See:

[Connecting to instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance)

Comment: Thank you very much, so I need to assign an ip address to a VM instance, then I would be able to SSH into it with default security setting (FW, NACL)?

Comment: If your Compute Engine VMs have public IP address then yes, you can login to them over the Internet and that includes from a Cloud Shell environment.  Alternatively, create one Compute Engine with a public IP address and then login to it.  From there, you will have network connection to ALL the other Compute Engines.  This is the pattern known as a bastion host.

Comment: Thank you, I've just updated my post with my testing result.

Comment: Have added some more details in the answer.  Please review.  Obviously, after review, feel free to update with more questions or clarification as needed.  Again, thank you for the quality of your questions and your protocol for updating the question so that it is easy to see what you changed.